# How to idiomatically add a TimeUnit to a DateTime object?

Tags: c#, datetime

So there is a `TimeUnit` enum that looks like this

```
public enum TimeUnit
{
    Days,
    Weeks,
    Months,
    Years,
    Hours,
    Minutes,
    Seconds,
    Milliseconds,
    Microseconds
}
```

and I have a static method AddPeriod like this

```
public static DateTime AddPeriod(DateTime dateTime,Period period)
{
    switch (period.Units)
    {
        case TimeUnit.Days:
            {
                return dateTime.AddDays(period.Length);
            }
        case TimeUnit.Months:
            {
                return dateTime.AddMonths(period.Length);
            }
        case TimeUnit.Years:
            {
                return dateTime.AddYears(period.Length);
            }
        // every other TimeUnit enum with a similar switch statement
        default:
            {
                Log.Error("TimeUnit not implemented: " + period.Units);
                return dateTime;
            }
    }
}
```

But while I was implementing this it felt like there must be a nicer way to simply add the corresponding TimeUnit than a massive switch statement.... does this look like a sound approach or am I missing something more clear or idiomatic?

Comment: If this code works then I think this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network like [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *Idiomatically*, you shouldn't use those custom classes and should use a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) to represent a time span (or a time period). It may or may not be feasable in your case.

Comment: Just to double check - you are aware of the TimeSpan class aren't you?

Comment: Is your period class a re-implementation of TimeSpan? Or is it http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Period.htm ?

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<TimeUnit, TimeSpan> `

Answer (score 2):

One of nasty way is to use reflection:

```
var method = dateTime.GetType()
                     .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .SingleOrDefault(mi => mi.Name.EndsWith(period.Units.ToString();

method.Invoke(dateTime, period.Length);
```

But is nasty, ugly, and can introduce bugs. It is not for real use :-) Consider using `TimeSpan`, like mentioned in comments.